# Search only text files in VS2012 "Find in Files"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In the Find in Files dialog (Ctrl-Shift-F), is there any way to search only text files in Visual Studio 2012?

I am working on a website that has 100,000's of images.

When I search for a string apparently it searches through all the .jpg and other non-text files (unless you specify the **file extension(s)** which sometimes **you can't do** because you just can't tell where the string might appear)

Answer (score 1):

The find-dialog gives you an option to restrict the search: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Find and Replace window has **Look at these file types** drop down control. You can write here file extension (*.txt, *.cs etc.) what you want to search in it.

[image: Fing And Replace]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the file types filter should include .txt, .aspx, etc.